# Career switch from a Statistician to Cryptography Research

Tags: encryption

I am currently working as a statistician, and I hope to do a career switch to cryptography as I have become interested in cryptography research. I currently have a bachelor's degree in mathematics as well as working experience as a statistician.

What is the best way to do a mid-career switch for a statistician? Also, because I have knowledge and experience in statistics, I want to leverage my statistics background as best as possible for pursuing research in cryptography. Which research areas in cryptography would allow me to do so?

Comment: There is a lot of statistics in side channel analysis for sure, DPA attacks are of course the most obvious one. In general I think the analysis of ciphers probably contains more math than the descriptions of the ciphers themselves. So yeah, analize a few schemes such as ciphers, hash functions or asymmetric primitives and see if you like it.

Comment: `I have knowledge and experience in statistics, I want to leverage my statistics background as best as possible for pursuing research in cryptography. Which research areas in cryptography would allow me to do so?` is probably the only content that should really be present in the question. `What is the best way to do a mid-career switch for a statistician?` is definitely not on-topic for our site.

Comment: We decided to leave this message for a while for any interesting comments; if you want to become a cryptographer, please go for it! However, due to multiple problems with such questions, I've had to put it on hold in the end...